# Gmail message "Show details" pop-up box is is hidden upon mouse-over when InboxSDK chrome extension is installed

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, gmail, inboxsdk

I am developing a chrome extension for Gmail using [InboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/). I have an obscure, but frustrating issue. The email message "Show details" pop-up box disappears upon mouse-over whenever the extension is installed. The extension does not directly interact with the pop-up in any way. The issue usually goes away after a few replicating it a few times in a row for a thread.

I've looked at the live html and css of the page to see what's going on. The visibility css tag for the details pop-up is switching from "visible" to "hidden" against my will.

I expect for the pop-up to stay visible until I click outside outside of the pop-up. This is it's normal behavior.

Comment: You'll have to debug it. Maybe by using the divide-and-conquer approach where you comment your code in progressive halves recursively until you find the culprit.

Comment: @wOxxOm not the solution that I was hoping for but still good advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself when I updated my Chrome to Version 72.0.3626.96. This question is closed.